# how can i delete system extensions in macOS

Tags: macos, system-settings

[image]

I don't know which path this extension exists in

Comment: Did you look inside the Applications folder? Or used Spotlight to locate it?

Comment: System preference -> Extensions

Comment: after install office, OneNote was add, after uninstall office, OneNote still in System Preference -> Extensions

Comment: Is OneNote.app still in /Applications? Does it still show up in Spotlight?

Comment: /Applications removed，can‘t show up

Comment: Was this installed with MS Office? If so you need to use the original installer to then *remove* office and all of its components